# Ajax Call in PHP and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

This is my functions.php script containing the following code. The array is encoded into JSON.

**functions.php**

```
 $final['custom']['main'] = queryCustom($conn, $id);
 echo json_encode($final);
```

My **global.js** has the following code which makes an AJAX request in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions.php", // file to reach Ajax call
            dataType: "json", 
            data: { 
                action: 'custom',
                id: id,
                  },
                success:
                function(data) {

                setCustom(data.custom);
```

I want to know what the `data` contains in `function(data)`? The `setCustom(data.custom)`, what does this mean here? Can someone provide me an explanation of this please?

Comment: Please give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data contains an object literal provided by the server side json_encode(). It's been automatically parsed because the data type is set to json.

example:

PHP:

```
$final['custom']['main'] = queryCustom($conn, $id);
echo json_encode($final);
```

Will give the following json string (formatted for better understanding):

```
{
    "custom": {
        "main":[
            {
                "symbol":"MAP4",
                "official_ID":"112315"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The ajax call above is set to datatype json. jQuery knows if this datatype is set, it will automatically parse the string to an object literal.

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url.php", // file to reach Ajax call
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(data) {
        var main = data.custom;
        console.log(main); // returns the child object with "main"
    }
});
```

data contains the initial object, custom is a child object of data and main is a child object of custom.

Comment: Thanks for the informative replay Mr @Tyr. 

When I echo json_encode($final);, I get the following output: 
`{"custom":{"main":[{"symbol":"MAP4","official_ID":"112315"}]}}`

Can you edit your answer with regard to my output please ? 
Then I'll understand at 100%

Comment: Awesome understanding ! Thank you loads Mr Tyr.

Comment: So what is printed on the console.log is the MAP4 and 112315, right ?

Comment: It is. As you can see main is an array (shown by the [ ] braces) which contains an object with MAP4 and 112315. So if you want to have access to the object you have to use `main[0].symbol` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

**Success:** A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments:

- **Data Returned From The Server**
- **Status**
- **jqXHR** (XMLHttpRequest Object)

In your PHP code you've added `echo json_encode($final);` which will be returned if the request is completed successfully. The response will be passed to `data` which you can later use in your front-end code.

You can read more about `$.ajax()` at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/